# Select row by row in TOAD plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to TOAD and PLSQL. I have a TABLE which has 10 columns and one of them is STATUS. My goal is to select all rows that have status=0 and then send the rows 1 by 1 to an API.
The process of sending would be:

- get the rows that have status=0
- wrap the first one in a wrapper, send it via API and repeat until      all the rows are sent.

The API part is done, but I don't know how to select the rows 1by1 to wrap them and send them individually.

I know this is a noob question and the title doesn't quiet match the problematics, but don't judge me pls. Any help would be great.

Comment: What kind of API ? A webservice ? A PLSQL stored proc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a loop. Something like this:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select id
                from your_table
                where status = 0)
  loop
    -- pass ID to your API; don't know how it looks like. Let's presume
    -- it is a stored procedure
    p_api (par_id => cur_r.id);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Kao i jučer: puno hvala!

Comment: Nema na čemu :)